# How to get Automapper to map an attribute that is part of another table

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

I have 3 tables that are related. Employee, Relative, RelationTypeCatalog. The relationship is `IX_Relatives_EmployeeId`  and `IX_Relatives_RelationTypeCatalogId` . What I'm trying to achieve is that when returning a list of relatives for an employee, I want the field 'Relationship' to show the value stored in 'RelationType' that is a property of the RelationTypeCatalog class.

Me being new to coding and automapper, I could really use some help and guidance. I was able to get as far as getting the "Relationship" field as null. Here is some code

```
    public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public string DNI { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Relative> Relatives { get; set; }
        
    }

    public class Relative
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public Employee Employee { get; set; }
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public RelationTypeCatalog RelationTypeCatalog { get; set; }
        public int RelationTypeCatalogId { get; set; }   
    }

    public class RelationTypeCatalog
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string RelationType { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Relative> Relatives { get; set; }

    }

    public class RelativeToReturnDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Relationship { get; set; }

    }

and here is the Automapper

    public class AutoMapperProfiles : Profile
    {
          CreateMap<Relative, RelativeToReturnDto>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Age,
            opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.DateOfBirth.CalculateAge()))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Relationship,
            opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.RelationTypeCatalog.RelationType));
    }
```

Here is the JSON response I get.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Camacho",
    "age": 29,
    "dni": "(865) 494-2026",
    "relatives": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Diego",
            "age": 15,
            "relationship": null
        }
}
```

What I expect is to get `"relationship": "Espouse"`
which is the corresponding value in 'RelationType' field

Comment: This looks like it should work - are you sure that RelationTypeCatalog has a value prior to mapping it?

Comment: Yes, Rob, I've made a simple test of adding the 'RelationTypeCatalogId' to the 'RelativeToReturnDto' fields and it returns a value, I just can't get automapper to figure out whats the 'RelationType'

Comment: I don't see how RelationTypeCatalogId has any bearing on the issue at hand - can you confirm via the debugger or some other method that you Relative object does in fact have a non-null RelationTypeCatalog with the property RelationType set to espouse BEFORE you attempt to map it to your DTO.

Comment: You are right, thank you. The relationType is, in fact, null before the map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Rob states the issue seems to be caused by your input and not by `AutoMapper`, as in the following example the `Relationship` is mapped:

```
var mapper = new Mapper(new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfile<AutoMapperProfiles>()));
var relative = new Relative { RelationTypeCatalog = new RelationTypeCatalog { RelationType = "rel1" } };
var dto = mapper.Map<RelativeToReturnDto>(relative);
Debug.Assert(dto.Relationship == "rel1");
```